# Has Lorem ipsum ever been analyzed as a poem by literary critics or scholars?

Tags: poetry

[Lorem ipsum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorem_ipsum) is a popular filler text. Have any literary critics or scholars analyzed it as a poem?

Here's an example of Lorem ipsum:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as primarily opinion-based. As far as I know, there is no objective definition of "poem" which would enable one to say definitively whether a given piece of text is a poem or not.

Comment: Also voting to close, per rand's reasons

Comment: I'm feeling a bit prose-aic about this question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## No.

The text isn't even real latin; it's been edited to make *no sense*. It's literally nonsense text.

> The lorem ipsum text is typically a scrambled section of De finibus bonorum et malorum, a 1st-century BC Latin text by Cicero, with words altered, added, and removed to make it nonsensical, improper Latin

<sup>- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorem_ipsum) (citing  "[Lorem Ipsum - All the facts - Lipsum generator](http://www.lipsum.com/)" from www.lipsum.com)</sup>

It's been scrambled and has parts removed of added, so that it doesn't make sense. Here's a translation from Wikipedia<sup>1</sup>:

> loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great To take a trivial example, which of us ever laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who find fault  chooses to enjoy a pleasure one  avoids a pain produces no blinded by desire, that they cannot foresee blame belongs to those who fail in their duty through weakness of will, which is the same as saying through shrinking from toil

<sub>Here's from [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/Lorem%20ipsum%20dolor%20sit%20amet%2C%20consectetur%20adipiscing%20elit%2C%20sed%20do%20eiusmod%20tempor%20incididunt%20ut%20labore%20et%20dolore%20magna%20aliqua.%20Ut%20enim%20ad%20minim%20veniam%2C%20quis%20nostrud%20exercitation%20ullamco%20laboris%20nisi%20ut%20aliquip%20ex%20ea%20commodo%20consequat.%20Duis%20aute%20irure%20dolor%20in%20reprehenderit%20in%20voluptate%20velit%20esse%20cillum%20dolore%20eu%20fugiat%20nulla%20pariatur.%20Excepteur%20sint%20occaecat%20cupidatat%20non%20proident%2C%20sunt%20in%20culpa%20qui%20officia%20deserunt%20mollit%20anim%20id%20est%20laborum.), translating your example text in the question:</sub>

> <sub>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod and vitality, tempor ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Over the years come, who nostrud aliquip advantage from it, but for to work, exercise, school district. Duis cillum, however, want to be a pain in the pleasure of football irure flee from pain to find produces no resultant. Excepteur blinds are not cupidatat proident, it is soothing to the soul, that is, they deserted the general chapter be at fault who fulfill an office of their labors.</sub>

The original text was from a [philosophy book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_finibus_bonorum_et_malorum), and they took the text from a part on Hedonism and was then edited. So:

**Not a poem at all**.

---

Edit based on the edit of the question:

**Probably not**, as there would be no sense in analyzing it as a poem since it fairly obviously *wasn't intended to be a poem*.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>Actually, they gave the translation of the text before it  was edited no make it nonsense, and had bolded the parts used. I just copied the bolded part.</sub>

Comment: Just because it's nonsense doesn't mean it isn't a poem (see Jabberwocky).

Comment: @Randal'Thor true. I'v edited the answer to clarify.

Comment: @kenorb I added a line.

Comment: But see also ["found poetry"](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Found_poetry&oldid=748057769)